# When AKS deletes public IPs it assigns to LoadBalancer type of services?

Tags: azure-container-service

I have AKS cluster on which I constantly deploy and then delete namespaces with applications which mostly exposed by LoadBalancer type of services.

There are max 20 applications with public ip's at any given time thought in Resource Group which holds AKS nodes I see 20 * 4.5 public ip addresses.

My question is when are these deleted if at all ?

Answer (score 0):

Every new service that you expose through type loadbalancer creates a public ip and sets it on the Azure loadbalancer.

When you delete a service the public ip will be removed by Azure.

Comment: AKS does not create load balancer each time you create kubernetes service of type load balancer. It creates public ip and assigns a record 'Frontend IP configuration'. To lo single load balancer AKS cluster has. This is why this happens in first place.

Comment: You are right that it does not create a loadbalancer every time you create a new kubernetes service. I guess I should be more specific in my answer in the future. Hope it gave some answer to you question